# doctest Expected nothing

Tags: python, doctest

I am confused by this doctest problem.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Match = namedtuple('Match', ['token_string', 'normalised_token',
                     'brand_name', 'brand_id',
                     'score'])

def make_match(tokens, normalised, brand, score):
    """
    Examples:
    >>> make_match('Jack Jones','JackJones',('Jack Jones','X023'),0.6)==Match('Jack Jones','JackJones','Jack Jones','X023',0.6)
    >>> True 
    >>> make_match('Jack Jones','JackJones',('Jack Jones','X023'),0.6)==('Jack Jones','JackJones','Jack Jones','X023',0.6)
    >>> True
    """
    return Match(token_string=tokens,
         normalised_token=normalised,
         brand_name=brand[0],
         brand_id=brand[1],
         score=score)
```

And then I got test failure like this:

```
Failed example:
make_match('Jack Jones','JackJones',('Jack Jones','X023'),0.6)==Match('Jack Jones','JackJones','Jack Jones','X023',0.6)
Expected nothing
Got:
True
**********************************************************************
File "utilization.py", line 15, in utilization.make_match
Failed example:
True 
Expected nothing
Got:
True
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
4 of   4 in utilization.make_match
***Test Failed*** 4 failures.
```

That is strange. Shouldn't I already declared to expect "True" ?

Thank you very much

Comment: seems like you fail some test. can you add the code of the test? I think the test expects nothing while this statement return True

Comment: @Elisha this is `doctest`; the test code is in the docstring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test case formatting is incorrect, it doesn't match what you would see in the interpreter. For example, instead of:

```
>>> make_match('Jack Jones','JackJones',('Jack Jones','X023'),0.6)==Match('Jack Jones','JackJones','Jack Jones','X023',0.6)
>>> True
```

You should have:

```
>>> make_match('Jack Jones','JackJones',('Jack Jones','X023'),0.6)==Match('Jack Jones','JackJones','Jack Jones','X023',0.6)
True
```

Note the `>>>` is not present for the output. This is also why you see four tests instead of the two you were expecting; `True` was interpreted as a new test, not the expected outcome for the previous test.